# Using rel attribute in document on change function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use below code for dynamic textbox. When I will change ID=iuname1 it has to show result in FffinalResult1. Then when I will change ID=iuname2 it has to show result in FffinalResult2. but it don't.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var counter = 0;
$(function () {
    $("#btnAdd").bind("click", function () {
        var div = $("<div />");


        div.html(GetDynamicTextBox(""));
        $("#TextBoxContainer").append(div);


    });



});
function GetDynamicTextBox() {
    counter++;
    return 'Item Code : <select name="iuname" id="iuname" rel="' + counter + '" class="iuname" >'+
            <?php foreach($tItem as $row) : ?>
              '<option value="<?php echo $row->ProductID;?>"><?php echo $row->ProductID;?></option>'+
            <?php endforeach;?>
        '</select>'+

        ' Batch : <input id="buname" name="buname" rel="' + counter + '" class="buname">'+

        </div>'); 
        '<div rel="' + counter + '" class="FffinalResult" id=FFinalResult" ></div>'+

        '<br/>'


}
</script>
```

And document on change function is below.

```
<script>

$(document).on('change', $(".iuname[rel='"+ counter + "']"), function(){
var val = $(this).val();
var text = $(this).find('option:selected').text();

$(".FFffinalResultt[rel='"+ counter + "']").text(val);

});

</script>
```

How it will works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code will always give `values` for last inserted elements as `counter` will be increasing each time you add `elements`! So I would suggest to use `class` here instead of `id`!

```
var counter = 0;// You can keep this to generate unique `id` but bind events to class

$(function () {
    $("#btnAdd").bind("click", function () {
        var div = $("<div />");
        div.html(GetDynamicTextBox(""));
        $("#TextBoxContainer").append(div);
    });
});

function GetDynamicTextBox() {
     counter++;
     return 
        'Item Code : <select name="iuname" id="iuname_'+counter+'" rel="' + counter + '" class="iuname" >'+
               <?php foreach($tItem as $row) : ?>
                  '<option value="<?php echo $row->ProductID;?>"><?php echo $row->ProductID;?></option>'+
               <?php endforeach;?>
    '       </select>'+
    ' Batch : <input id="buname_'+counter+'" name="buname" rel="' + counter + '" class="buname">'+ 
    '<div rel="' + counter + '" class="FffinalResult" id="FFinalResult_'+counter+'" ></div>'+
    '<br/>';
```

}

And `event binding` to `class`

```
$(document).on('change', ".iuname", function(){
   var val = $(this).val();
   var text = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
   $(this).siblings(".FffinalResultt").text(val); //get its sibling element
});
```

Comment: You are right its working for this code. Now I'm changing above code using keyup instead of onchange. For this code siblings not working.@Guruprasad Rao

Comment: @MasudSarker There isn't any event called `.keyup` for `select` element! So obviously it will not work..